# Initiating a SOAP Array on Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, soap

I am trying to initialize or create an array of a soap call:

```
Array_Of_ProductIdentifierClinicalType = array of ProductIdentifierClinicalType;
```

This is the way that I am trying to initialize it:

```
Product[0].IdentifierType := Array_Of_ProductIdentifierClinicalType.Create();
```

When I run the application I get this error: Access Violation at address...

[image]

The question would be: How to initialize this soap call??

Thank you for your time!!!!
You can do a WSDL import on: http://axelcarreras.dyndns.biz:3434/WSAlchemy.wsdl

```
procedure TFrmMain.Button16Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  ExcludeExpiradas: String;
  Serv: AlchemyServiceSoap;
  req: AlchemyClinical;
  element: AlchemyClinicalRequest;
  Prescribed: PrescribedType;
  //Prescribing: Prescribing
  Prescribing: PrescribedType;
  alc: AlchemyIdentifierType;
  D: TXSDate;
  Counter: Integer;
  ProductStr: AlchemyIdentifierClinicalType;


begin

  With DM do
  begin
    ExcludeExpiradas := ' and (' + chr(39) +  DateToStr(Date) + chr(39) + ' < (FECHARECETA + 180)) ';
    CDSRx_Procesadas.Close;
    CDSRx_Procesadas.CommandText := 'SELECT * ' +
    ' FROM RX_PROCESADAS WHERE ' +
    ' (NUMERORECETA IS NOT NULL AND CANTIDAD_DISPONIBLE > 0)' +
     ExcludeExpiradas +
    ' and NumeroCliente = ' + CDSPacientesNumeroCliente.asString +
    ' Order by NumeroReceta';
    //ShowMessage(CDSRx_Procesadas.CommandText);
    CDSRx_Procesadas.Open;

    ProductStr := AlchemyIdentifierClinicalType.Create;
    With ProductStr do
    begin
      Identifier := 1;
    end;

    element := AlchemyClinicalRequest.Create;
    //Prescribed := PrescribedType.Create;
    With element do
    begin
      With Prescribed do
      begin
        Counter := 0;
        while not CDSRx_Procesadas.eof do
        begin
          Product := Array_Of_ProductIdentifierClinicalType.Create();
          With Product[0] do
          begin
            IdentifierType := ProductIdentifierTypeEnum.NDC9;
            Identifier := Copy(DM.CDSInventarioNDC.Value, 1, 9);
          end;
          Counter := Counter + 1;
          CDSRx_Procesadas.Next;
        end;
      end;
      With Prescribing do
      begin
        Counter := 0;
        Product[0].IdentifierType := ProductIdentifierTypeEnum.AlchemyProductID;
        Product[0].Identifier := Copy(DM.CDSInventarioNDC.Value, 1, 9);
        Counter := Counter + 1;
      end;
      With PatientDemographics do
      begin
        while not CDSAlergies.Eof do
        begin
          Allergy.AllergySubstanceClass[0].Identifier := CDSAlergiesNOALERGIA.Value;
          CDSAlergies.Next;
        end;
        if CDSPacientesSEXO.Value = 1 then
          Gender := GenderTypeEnum.Male
        else
          Gender := GenderTypeEnum.Female;

        D := TXSDate.Create;
        D.AsDate := CDSPacientesFECHANACIMIENTO.AsDateTime;
        DateOfBirth := D;
      end;
      With RequestedOperations do
      begin
        DrugToDrug := True;
        //DuplicateTherapy
        Allergy := True;

        With WarningLabels do
        begin
          Request := True;
          LanguageCode := 'en-US';
          MaxLines := 5;
          CharsPerLine := 24;
        end;
        With DoseScreening do
        begin
          Request := True;
        end;
        AdverseReactions.Request := True;
      end;
      IgnorePrescribed := False;
      IncludeConsumerNotes := True;
      IncludeProfessionalNotes := True;
    end;
  end;
end;*
```

Comment: Declare a variable of the array type and initialize with `SetLength(MyArray, 1);`

Comment: Do you have any more code? What is `Product`? How did you allocate `Product`?

Comment: Yes I have more code where can I send it to?

Comment: Dissect the relevant code, edit your question and add that code here.

Comment: I just posted the code that I am utilizing...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this line of code from the question is accurate:

```
Array_Of_ProductIdentifierClinicalType = array of ProductIdentifierClinicalType;
```

then the problem lies here:

```
Product := Array_Of_ProductIdentifierClinicalType.Create();
```

This is a dynamic array constructor. It creates a dynamic array of length equal to the number of parameters to the constructor. And then assigns each element of the array, in turn, to the parameters passed.

Consider an example using `TBytes = array of Byte`.

```
Bytes := TBytes.Create(1, 2, 3);
```

This initialises `Bytes` to be an array of length 3 and having values 1, 2 and 3.

Now, let's look at your code again. This initialises `Product` to be an array of length 0. So when you access `Product[0]` that results in a runtime error because the array index is out of bounds.

To solve the problem you will need to make sure that the array is initialised to have sufficient elements. One option is certainly to use a dynamic array constructor. Another is to use `SetLength`. I suspect that your understanding of Delphi's dynamic arrays is poor. I suggest that you consult the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays).

Comment: Please vote and accept answers. At the moment you are taking but not giving. Read my link in the comment to your question.

Comment: I also struggled with this as Code Completion (a.k.a. Intellisense) didn't show up any methods or properties, so I thought `Create` wasn't available. But you can just do `someobj.prop := Array_Of_String.Create('myString')` where `Array_Of_String = array of string;`